# C++ Vector ADT Class

Tags: c++, class, templates, vector

I keep getting this error when compiling. Im not sure if i am properly creating the vector in the main.cpp file. I have attached the vector.h which is correct. DOes anyone know exactly i could create a vector in the main so i can add elements and use the functions in the header file?

```
In file included from Vectormain.cpp:5:0:
vector.h: In instantiation of ‘void Vector<T>::reserve(unsigned int) [with T = int]’:
vector.h:23:10:   required from ‘Vector<T>::Vector(unsigned int) [with T = int]’
Vectormain.cpp:16:20:   required from here
vector.h:133:6: error: ‘copy’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
  copy(buffer, buffer + mySize, newBuffer);
      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/locale_facets.h:48:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/basic_ios.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from Vectormain.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:293:5: note: ‘template<class _CharT> typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<_Tp>::__value, std::ostreambuf_iterator<_CharT> >::__type std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>, std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>, std::ostreambuf_iterator<_CharT>)’ declared here, later in the translation unit
     copy(istreambuf_iterator<_CharT> __first,
```

Am i using the push_back function properly in the Main code:?
I tried Vector V1(100); // i know this is how you would if you were using the stdtemplate library.
but is it the same for this vector class?

```
//VectorMain.cpp

#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include "vector.h"

using namespace std;

void sieve(Vector<int>&);

int main()
{
    //vector of size 100;
    //fill with some default values
    int N = 100;
    Vector<int> V1(100);


    //cout << V1.size();
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
    {
        V1.push_back(-1);
    }
    // call sieve


    //print out  vector after seive
    //all non-0 values are prime numbers

    return 0;
}

void sieve(Vector<int> & values)
{
    unsigned int max = values.size();

    for(int i = 0; 1 < max; i++)
    {
        values[i] = i;
    }

    for(int i = 2; i <= max; i++)
    {
        if(values[i] != 0)
        {
            for(int j = i + i; j < max; j += i)
            {
                values[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Im trying to implement a template class of Vector rather than using"#include<>"

Vector.h:

```
//vector.h

#ifndef VECTOR_H_
#define VECTOR_H_
#include<algorithm>
#include<cassert>


template<class T>
class Vector
{
public:
    typedef T * iterator;
    typedef T value_type;

    Vector()
        : buffer(0), mySize(0), myCapacity(0)
    {}

    Vector(unsigned int size)
        : buffer(0)
    {
        reserve(size);
    }

    Vector(unsigned int size, T initial)
    {
        reserve(size);
        fill(buffer,buffer+size, initial);
        mySize = size;
    }

    Vector(Vector& v)
        : buffer(0)
    {
        reserve(v.myCapacity);
        copy(v.begin(), v.end(), begin());
        mySize = v.mySize;
    }

    ~Vector()
    {
        delete [ ] buffer;
    }

    T& back() const
    {
        return buffer[mySize-1];
    }

    T& front() const
    {
        return buffer[0];
    }

    iterator begin() 
    { 
        return buffer;
    }

    iterator end() 
    { 
        return begin() + mySize;
    }

    int capacity() 
    { 
        return myCapacity;
    }

    unsigned int size() 
    { 
        return mySize;
    }

    bool empty() 
    { 
        return mySize == 0;
    }

    void pop_back() 
    {
        mySize--;
    }

    void push_back(T);  

    void reserve(unsigned int); 

    void resize(unsigned int, T);

    T& operator [ ](unsigned int index)
    {
        return buffer[index];
    }

    virtual void insert(unsigned int, T);

    /*^^virtual*/ void insert(iterator, T); 

    void erase(unsigned int);

    void erase(iterator);

protected:

    unsigned int mySize;

    unsigned int myCapacity;

    T * buffer;
};


// MEMBER FUNCTIONS
template<class T>

void Vector<T>::reserve(unsigned int newCap)
{
    if(buffer == 0) 
    {
        mySize = 0;
        myCapacity = 0;
    }
    if(newCap <= myCapacity)
    { 
        return;
    }

    T * newBuffer = new T[newCap];
    assert(newBuffer);

    copy(buffer, buffer + mySize, newBuffer);

    myCapacity = newCap;
    delete [ ] buffer;
    buffer = newBuffer;
}

template<class T>

void Vector<T>::resize(unsigned int newSize, T pad_value)
{
    reserve(newSize);
    fill(buffer, buffer + newSize, pad_value);
    mySize = newSize;
}

template<class T>

void Vector<T>::push_back(T value)
{
    if(mySize >= myCapacity)
    {
        reserve(myCapacity + 5); // more space
    }
    buffer[mySize++] = value; 
}

// insert new item x at location ref’ed by itr;
//template <class T>
//void Vector<T>::insert(iterator itr, T x)
//{
//  // is there room for x and is iterator 
//  // within range?
//  assert(mySize < myCapacity);
//  assert(itr >= begin());
//  assert(itr < end());
//  // init an iterator to end of vector;
//  // position past last element stored;
//  iterator ptr = end();
//  // move ptr from right to left until itr
//  // is reached; keep coping elm under ptr
//  // one position to the right;
//  while(ptr > itr)
//  {
//      *ptr = *(ptr - 1);
//      ptr--;
//  }
//  // store new elm x at position ref’ed by itr;
//  // update size;
//  *itr = x; 
//  mySize++; 
//}
// QUESTION: what happens when you try to insert 
// into a vector that is filled to capacity?

// erase the element ref’ed by itr;
//template <class T>
//void Vector<T>::erase(iterator itr)
//{
//  // is itr within range?
//  assert(itr >= begin() && itr < end());
//// itr points to null; do nothing
//  if(itr == 0)
//      return;

//// itr points to last elm in vector;
//// pop_back does the job;
//  if(itr == end() - 1)
//{
//  pop_back();
//  return;
//}
//  //for position ref’ed by itr until the last
//  // filled position, copy each elm position to 
//  // the left; count down size;
//  while(itr < end())
//  {
//      *itr = *(itr  + 1);
//      itr++;
//  }
//  mySize--;
//}
#endif
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using `std::vector`?

Comment: Masochism or classwork. The latter is more likely. Luis Garcia, You likely need a `std::` on the front of `copy`.

Comment: definitely classwork.

Comment: In the function using `copy`, add a `using std::copy;`.